# Map line numbers between commits

Tags: git

Say I have a file in a git repo which contains (among others) a line that was introduced in commit `a` (which I can see with `git blame`). Say this line is the 5th line in the file. Now, commit `a` lies back some time, so some other stuff in the file has changed in the meantime. In particular, a line above the one in question was removed; therefore, in commit `a`, my line was line 6.

My question now is: How can I obtain a mapping between the line number in HEAD and the line number in some other commit (the commit where the line was introduced/changed, or one after that)? In my example, I want a map that looks like the following (for input `5`):

- HEAD: 5
- `a`: 6
- `b` (another commit between `a` and HEAD): 7

Since the line content might be in the file multiple times, I cannot simply search for that, but obviously git knows which line is which (-> `git blame`).

Is there a 'pure' git solution, or are there any libraries for this?

Comment: `'pure' git solution` i am not aware. But if you want to do it a few times you could just compare contents of the file from the two commits. I am curious why this ask or is there anything more you are looking for.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni I definitely need an automated solution; my goal is to perform some operations on the file in different commits, which require information about this one line

Comment: Okay, I get it.

Comment: The `git blame` command has to do rather a lot of computation to get the mapping. In simpler cases, a diff between the two snapshots might get you the right answer, but ideally, if you're finding this with `git blame` in the first place, it would be nice to have `git blame` save the answer. This is especially tricky when the line doesn't exist in the `HEAD` version at all. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Taking an example from the Linux kernel. Let's say we're looking for this line, which is line `2616` in `v5.0` and we want to know what it ends up being in `v5.15`:

```
$ git grep -n 'SYSCALL_DEFINE.*unshare' v5.0 -- kernel/fork.c 
v5.0:kernel/fork.c:2616:SYSCALL_DEFINE1(unshare, unsigned long, unshare_flags)
```

We can look it up directly in the new version, keeping in mind this is just so we can know what the correct answer should be:

```
$ git grep -n 'SYSCALL_DEFINE.*unshare' v5.15 -- kernel/fork.c 
v5.15:kernel/fork.c:3149:SYSCALL_DEFINE1(unshare, unsigned long, unshare_flags)
```

To answer the question, we could maybe use `git blame` like this:

```
$ git blame -L 2616,+1 --reverse v5.0..v5.15 --porcelain -- kernel/fork.c 
8bb7eca972ad531c9b149c0a51ab43a417385813 3149 2616 1
[...]
```

It seems to have found the correct answer: `3149`.

I'm not 100% sure if this works in the general case, but thought I would share what I'd found.